Finding a bounded and divergent sequence $(a_n)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n=0$
I want to find a bounded and divergent sequence $(a_n)$ with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n=0,$$
and I prefer that $a_n=f(n)$ where the function $f$ is elementary, so that this answer is not relevant. The sequence $a_n=\sin(n)$ is bounded and divergent, but I'm not sure if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(n+1)-\sin(n)=0.$$ I also came up with $a_n=\sin(\sqrt n),$ and from the inequality $|\sin x-\sin y|\leq |x-y|$ together with (by multiplying by the conjugate) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=0,$$ we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\sqrt{n+1})-\sin(\sqrt n)=0.$$ I'm having trouble showing that $a_n=\sin(\sqrt n)$ diverges.
So I need help with determining if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(n+1)-\sin(n)=0,$$
and also if $a_n=\sin(\sqrt n)$ diverges. Even if it's not true that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(n+1)-\sin(n)=0,$$ I would still like to know if the sequence $b_n=\sin(n+1)-\sin(n)$ diverges, and if not, what can be said about its limit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

For one way to show that $a_n = \sin(\sqrt{n})$ diverges, I will prove the following more generalized result:
Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on some interval $[R_0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = 0$.  Then $\limsup_{n\to \infty} f(n) = \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.
Proof: Since $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$, it is easy to see that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(n) \le \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.  For the other direction, I will suppose that $L := \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is finite; the infinite cases $L = +\infty$ and $L = -\infty$ can be done similarly.  Now, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $R \in \mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $x > R$, then $|f'(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.  Also, there exists $x_0 > R$ with $L - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < f(x_0) \le L$.  Now, if we consider $n := \lceil x_0 \rceil$, a simple argument using the mean value theorem shows that $f(n) > L - \varepsilon$.  From this argument, we can conclude that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(n) \ge L$ as well.
The argument for $\liminf$ is similar. $\square$
As a corollary, we can conclude that the sequence $(f(n))_{n=1}^\infty$ converges if and only if the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite.  Now just apply this in the case $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt{x})$.

The mean value theorem applied to the function $f(x) = \sin\sqrt x$ on the interval $[n,n+1]$ tells us that
$$
\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt n) = f(n+1)-f(n) = f'(\xi) ((n+1)-n) = \frac{\cos\sqrt\xi}{2\sqrt\xi}
$$
for some $\xi\in(n,n+1)$. Therefore
$$
|\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt n)| = \frac{|\cos\sqrt\xi|}{2\sqrt\xi} \le \frac1{2\sqrt n},
$$
and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt n)) = 0$ by the squeeze theorem.
The same method could help investigate $\sin(n+1)-\sin n$: that sequence does not tend to $0$, but the mean value theorem offers one way of showing that it does diverge.

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt n)) = 0$ was already proved by the OP, who commented "That part I already answered myself in the question" when proposed a (now deleted) link to a duplicate of that proof. As for $\sin(n+1)-\sin n$, "it" is dense in $\left[-2\sin\frac12,2\sin\frac12\right]$.
